# How does Anacron works in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

How does the Anacron runs even after the system shutdowns in linux? How does it look for the commands to run after the system shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a backup script scheduled everyday at 11 PM as a regular cron job, and if your laptop is not up at 11 PM, your backup job will not be executed.

However, if you have the same job scheduled in anacron, you can be sure that it will be executed once the laptop come back up.

So what it means that Anacron wont execute at 11 PM as you laptop is off(and it doesn't have special power to switch on the laptop :) ), but it will surely execute whenever you switch on you laptop.

For mode details see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/anacron-examples/

Comment: Alright Thanks. So is there any way to run the cron jobs even after the system shutdowns like web based cron jobs? Only way is running cron jobs in servers?

Comment: That can be a separate question, which should be asked on http://superuser.com/, please mark this solved it answers the real query :)

Comment: There are plenty of details with usage of *anacron*, among which are: [ interaction with *cron* as essential part of scheduling ], [ running with *root* privelegy ], [ differences in format/syntax of commands to be scheduled ]. So, run search here and other SE sites, please, before posting new question. My regards to moderators.